# Creating an object with dynamic properties in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, object

I'm using linq to load a csv file, but because the csv may have any number of columns, the object that it returns will need dynamic properties, and I can't figure out how to do that.

```
var data = from row in csvData
       let col = row.Split(',')
       select new
              {
                  Field1 = data[0],
                  Field2 = data[1],
                  Field3 = data[2] // etc, etc
              };
```

If possible, I'd like to name the properties by the name given in the csv file, rather than field1, field2, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What would you do with this afterwards? If you know the names elsewhere and you're using .NET 4, you *could* use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) - populate it by using it as a dictionary, and then access the property names using dynamic typing later. But if it's *all* dynamic (i.e. you don't know anything statically anywhere), why don't you just use `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Do you know if the ExpandoObject would support intellisense? Say I return an ExpandoObject based on a Dictionary, would that object support intellisense so I can see the property names suggested?

Comment: @Joze: Not at compile-time, no. I believe there's debugger support though.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do is simply using arrays or even a Dictionary but if you want to do something cool with Dynamic check out Clay

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/18/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-2.aspx